# Creating a strongly typed view based on a custom model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I have need of a view that combines two entity models. I created a class that looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using FSDS.DataModels;

namespace FSDS.WebUX.Models
{
    public partial class ChainandJob
    {
        public ScheduleJobChain chain {get;set;} //this object has 6 properties
        public ScheduleJob job {get;set;} //this object has 8 properties.
    }
}
```

I created a new partial view using the "create" scaffolding. This is what it gives me:

```
@model FSDS.WebUX.Models.ChainandJob

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>ChainandJob</legend>

        <p>
             <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
 }

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Where are all the fields?

Comment: And you don't want to type it in yourself?

Comment: @bobek It won't be the end of the world if I have to, but I'm worried about all the wiring that VS is supposed to do (validation and such)

Comment: But you can just do what the answers tell you and you'll have all validation and such. Just because it isn't auto generated doesn't mean you can't just type it in.

Comment: @bobek, I think he was just confused since VS didn't auto-generate the view data like you would expect it to on a less abstract model.

Comment: This was q-n about VS rather than about C#/ASP.NET MVC, but its alright :)

Comment: @GarrettFogerlie You're right. I was expecting the view to be auto-populated, and was thrown for a loop when it wasn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to write it yourself, something like:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ChainandJob.chain.Bla)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ChainandJob.chain.Bla)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ChainandJob.job.Bla)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ChainandJob.job.Bla)
```

And so on.

**Edit**

Although I don't do it this way, you could have VS create a edit view for `SchedualJobChain`, and another one for `ScheduleJob` and cut the templates it creates into one for you view model. Don't forget the `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ChainandJob.chain.Id` etc.

Comment: OP will also need to add data annotations to his/her model in order for validation to occur, I believe.

Comment: @Forty-Two I think validation will work, as long as he has say `[Required]` on `public string Bla { get; set;}` it should throw a validation error if the string is `null`.

Comment: Ah yes, forgot there are models behind his model.  You are correct:)

Answer (score 2):

VS doesn't know your objects. Right after `<legend>ChainandJob</legend>` try adding

```
@EditorFor(m => m.chain.ChainProperty)
@ValidationMessageFor(m => m.chain.ChainProperty)

@EditorFor(m => m.job.JobProperty)
@ValidationMessageFor(m => m.job.JobProperty)
```

and things will be hunky dory :)
`EditorFor` will generate the default output for you, should you need to tweak it - feel free to do so.

Comment: I believe you need to have `m => m.chain` and you have to have an editor for each field in `chain` and `job`, VS won't scaffold this for you.

Comment: You right, I fixed, but I think it does not really matter, the guy was asking about the concept, rather than technique. You can figure out this minor details (especially - this is basics) once you get your concept together.